# Why is Plotly line chart throwing syntax error in layout line?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I am trying to create a line chart in Jupyter notebook using plot.ly, this is a first for me so I am trying from the kaggle guide. Anyways, I am getting a syntax error and can't figure out why:

```
trace1 = go.Scatter(
                    x = monarchs2001_tally.tag_state,
                    y = monarchs2001_tally.recovered_tags,
                    mode = "lines",
                    name = "2001 Season",
                    marker = dict(color = 'rgba(16, 112, 2, 0.8)'),

trace2 = go.Scatter(
                    x = monarchs2000_tally.tag_state,
                    y = monarchs2000_tally.recovered_tags,
                    mode = "lines",
                    name = "2000 Season",
                    marker = dict(color = 'rgba(80, 26, 80, 0.8)'),

data = [trace1, trace2]
lyt = dict(title = 'Monarch Butterflies Recovered Each Season',
              xaxis= dict(title= 'Tag State', ticklen= 5, zeroline= True)
              )
fig = dict(data = data, layout = layout)
iplot(fig)
```

File "", line 16
    lyt = dict(title = 'Monarch Butterflies Recovered Each Season',
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I know by commenting out the layout section out that the fig = section also throws up a syntax error.
Thanks for the help

Comment: You have stray `,`s after your `trace*` definitions. Not sure if that's the specific problem, but it'll probably cause some issue.

Comment: Neither `trace1` nor `trace2` has a closing parentheses at the end.